# .htaccess RewriteEngine RewriteRule 3 static params, recursive generic params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So want to accomplish(with .htaccess) that that I can rewrite this url:

> index.php?controller=ControllerName&method=MethodName&view=ViewName&key=value&key2=value2

To this:

> /ControllerName/MethodName/ViewName/?key=value&key2=value

This is the code i have now:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&view=$3&$4=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&view=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?controller=$1&method=$2&view=$3 [QSA,L]
```